# Creating a filter to switch between timezones in Tableau Report

Tags: datetime, timezone, tableau-api

I am adding a filter in Tableau to switch between timezones when looking at the report.

Currently, I have a date time field in MT and I want to have a filter where you can go back and forth between MT and CT.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Would it be better practice to add a new field  to my data source for the central timezone or to handle the conversion logic in Tableau?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in tableau within 2 steps:

1. Create a parameter with the strings of time zones that you want to display
2. Create a calculated field that is connected to this parameter and has a switch case to add or subtract time from your original timestamp.

If switching between timezones is done frequently then it is recommended to insert a column in your database itself. Depends on your data size and dashboard performance.